# How to work with zero dates ("0000-00-00") in Hibernate?

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have MySql table that has a date field with zeroes ("0000-00-00") as its default value (field cannot be null, I can't change table structure). Hibernate doesn't like zero dates and throws exception during read or save.

I managed to make it read records by setting MySql connection setting "zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull" that converts zero dates to nulls while retrieving records. It is all working fine until I try to save the record that has null date - it throws exception that date cannot be null.

So the question is - how to save record through Hibernate so date will appear as zeroes in a table?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to handle them, anyway?  Zero date--get out there and celebrate Jesus' birthday!  Why are you in front of your computer on such a momentous occasion! <G>

Comment: Year zero is nonexistent in the Julian and Gregorian calendar -- it jumps straight from 1 BC to 1 AD.  I can't really blame Hibernate for this one.

Comment: And a zero month and day number is not allowed anyway, even if the year was valid.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try to add an Hibernate Interceptor ([API](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html), [Doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/events.html)) and try to implement something in the onSave() method.

The following code may work:

```
static final Date ZERO_DATE = //0000-00-00

public boolean onSave(Object entity,
                  Serializable id,
                  Object[] state,
                  String[] propertyNames,
                  Type[] types)
           throws CallbackException {
    for(int i = 0; i< propertyNames.length; i++) {
        if(propertyNames[i].equals("dateFieldName") && state[i]==null) {
            state[i] = ZERO_DATE;
            return; //or may continue, if there are several such fields.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But what exactly is ZERO_DATE?

Comment: The java represntation of a date field with just zeroes.

Comment: Can you give an example how it looks? There is no such thing in java as date with all zeroes, that's why there is a problem with zero dates.

Comment: There is no such thing *anywhere* as a date with all zeroes. That thing in MySQL is not a date value.

Answer (score 0):

Ready and working solution for DATE '0000-00-00' and TIME '00:00:00': [How to map MySQL DATE '0000-00-00' & TIME '00:00:00' with Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28595887/how-to-map-mysql-date-0000-00-00-time-000000-with-hibernate)

Thanks Preston for the code and ChssPly76 for useful comments.